# iPhone 4S freezing after ios7 update

Tags: iphone

My iPhone 4S is lagging/ freezing an unbearable amount of time, glad to know resetting will help. However, Will 
resetting the iPhone 4S cause any data loss?

Answer (score 2):

To simply answer you question: it may.

There are several different options for resetting your phone, but no matter which method you choose, it is absolutely recommended to perform a complete backup of your device.

You have two primary options:

1. You can "Reset All Settings

   - This will erase all setting that you have configured on your device. This shouldn't cause any data loss but is worth backing up anyway. It may not do much for your problems though, in fixing them.
2. The other option is to "Erase All Content and Settings".

   - This will effectively wipe your iPhone and restore it like new (but still with iOS 7). You **will** have data loss with this option, but it may work best for you. If you have an iCloud backup, then it is easy to restore it after erasing the phone.